# Find the x,y coordinates for a specific value in a .csv file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv with thousands of distinct values. I need to figure out the x and y coordinates for a specific value.

I need to find value 756.243 in the .csv - is there something that will say '756.243 is at coordinates (235,1144)?

Sample Dataframe

```
    col1    col2
0   3       1.355
1   4       3.566
2   5       56.460
3   6       756.243
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.where`

```
i, c = np.where(df == 756.243)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.